# Sharing links to answers

Tags: discussion, badges

The [announcer](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer), [booster](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/60/booster) and [publicist](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/61/publicist) badges be awarded for sharing questions.

> Is there a reason why sharing answers is not rewarded in the same way?

Comment: see here: [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/178818)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Announcer badge work?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817/how-does-the-announcer-badge-work)

Comment: I see the answer to my first question is present in those links, but not the answer to my second. They state that the badges are for links to questions, but I couldn't see any explanation of why links to answers were not included. I will edit my post to make the distinction between my two questions more obvious.

Comment: By the way, I think the Publicist / Booster badges are way too easy to earn.  I earned 4 / 8 of them (resp.) without even trying, just from noncommitally sharing a few links here and there.  Publicist should be upped to 5000 views and Booster should be 1000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [feature change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903) of 2012-01-10:

> The Announcer, Booster and Publicist badges can now be [earned multiple times and they can also be earned for the same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118484/booster-badge-should-be-golden-or-easier-to-achieve/118509#118509). The time limit has also been removed. **Sharing direct links to answers now [also counts](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/816147#816147) towards these badges.** (my emphasis)

You must use the link provided by the "share" button at the bottom left of a post and make sure that the link includes your user number, so it should be of the form

`http://math.stackexchange.com/a/question_id/user_id`

in order for the system to be able to identify the traffic coming from the link *you* shared.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe this should be made clear in the badge descriptions.