# Badges for sharing questions on MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, badges, mathoverflow

The [announcer](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer), [booster](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/60/booster) and [publicist](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/61/publicist) badges are awarded for sharing questions (or answers, as has been discussed in [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8421/39599)). According to their [descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), only clicks from outside the Stack Exchange network count toward the badges.

> Is MathOverflow part of the Stack Exchange network?

I have a question on MO which contains a link to a question on MSE, but earning one of the badges above for that link seems dishonest.

Comment: If you don't want to earn a badge for posting a link, remove your user number `39599` from it: e.g. link to `http://math.stackexchange.com/q/194749/` instead of `http://math.stackexchange.com/q/194749/39599`. See  [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3444/49437).

Comment: I would add to Martin's excellent reply that badges don't matter, that a publicist badge and $1.65 will buy a cup of coffee, and that I, at least, won't even notice that you have the badge, much less how you obtained it. I hope this helps you worry less about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't (yet). ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I'll just add that Mariano wrote the word *yet* in his answer because there are plans (and they look quite realistically) to move MO to SE network, see [this discussion](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1416/mathoverflow-20/) at meta.MO.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the info - I wonder if they are aware that anyone with +200rep on _any_ other SE site will then be able to vote on MO. I thought that was one major reason for staying separate so far

Comment: The plans are quite real and will happen very soon! (One of the final hurdles was cleared last week...)